# Check if array contains an instance of a particular class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, instanceof, typeof

I come from .net background and new to typescript. I have an array that contains objects from different classes that implement a common interface. I would like to check if the array contains an object from a particular class. I tried using a combination of 'includes' and 'instanceof' but didn't succeed. Thanks in advance.

Suppose classes 'C1', 'C2' & 'C3' implement the interface 'Int1'.
Array 'array01' can hold the objects of classes that implement interface 'Int1'.

```
private static array01: Int1[] = [];

if(array01.includes(instanceof C1)) ??? //Want to check if 'array01' contains an object of class 'C1'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
private static array01: Int1[] = [];

if(array01.find(arr => arr instanceof C1)) {}
```

For array filter

```
private static array01: Int1[] = [];

if(array01.filter(arr => arr instanceof C1).length) {}
```

Comment: It seems that in the version of typescript I am using, 'find' is not available. Can I use 'filter' instead? Will the syntax be same?

Comment: Yes it will be same but then you will have to check for length > 0 for filtered array. Let me update the answer

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` is an operator, you cannot pass it as a value to be searched for to `includes`.

You are most likely looking for using [the `.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a callback:

```
if (array01.some(obj => obj instanceof C1)) …
```